# Getting radio button value from $.(ajax) and passing it in a SQL Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two sets of radio buttons: one for car brands and the other one for car models. Selecting "Audi" from the car brands will fetch all of the car models with the brand name "Audi" in my database through $(ajax).

```
function fetchModels() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script/rent/models.php",
    data: {dateFrom: selectedDateFrom, 
           dateTo: selectedDateTo, 
           destination: selectedDestination, 
           brand: selectedBrand},

    success: function(data) {
      $("#model-wrapper").html(data);
    }
    }
);} // fetchModels END


/* Whenever the selected car brand is changed, change the value of
   selectedBrand and run the function fetchModels(). */

    $('input[type=radio][name=brand]').on('change', function() {
        switch($(this).val()) {
          case 'Audi':
            selectedBrand = "Audi";
            break;
          case 'Toyota':
            selectedBrand = "Toyota";
            break;
          case 'Volkswagen':
            selectedBrand = "Volkswagen";
            break;
          case 'Volvo':
            selectedBrand = "Volvo";
            break;
        }

        fetchModels();

    });
```

My issue is that models.php can't get value from the selected car brand. It's likely caused by the fact that my car brands are also changed dynamically (the same way car models do) depending on which location is selected.

In other words, this while loop is run in `brands.php` to fetch the car brands:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $brand = $row['brand'];
  echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"brand\" value=\"$brand\">" . $brand . "</input>";
}
```

If I add a `<input type="radio" name="brand"/>` manually into the PHP-file it works fine, but it can't get the values from the generated ones.

A gif explaining my issue:

[image: A gif explaining my issue]

Audi and Volkswagen are radio buttons generated by `brands.php` while `Test` obviously isn't.

Comment: Hit right click, view-source and paste what the HTML output is

Comment: Your `switch` has a ton of duplication in it. Why not chain all those together and have just `selectedBrand = $(this).val()`?

Comment: @tadman Yes I've done that on the model selection already. I just haven't gotten around to doing it on the brand selection yet.

Comment: Your question is not very clear... what is the actual problem? Is `selectedBrand` undefined when you execute `fetchModels()`, or is the server failing to return results for the given `selectedBrand`? If the former - I don't see where `selectedBrand` is declared - it could be a scoping issue, but it's hard to tell without seeing your complete code.

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs #model-wrapper while selecting Audi or Volkswagen is `<div id="model-wrapper"></div>` and models.php is not run in the "Network" tab. Once I press the `Test` selection, the content in #model-wrapper is [this](https://i.gyazo.com/7c6ce38d4270435e19c0b032c368804a.png).

Comment: @corinnaerin yes, `selectedBrand` is undefined because it gets its value whenever the generated radio buttons are clicked and it's not registering when I click those.

Comment: You're switching on `value` but none of the value's match what you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image of [your generated HTML](https://embed.gyazo.com/7c6ce38d4270435e19c0b032c368804a.png) that you linked, the problem arises from the case statement you're using. The generated values are not present in the case statement, so no case is selected, so naturally `selectedBrand` is not set. It has nothing to do with static vs dynamically generated elements.

As was pointed out in a comment, the case statement is superfluous anyway. Replace it with `selectedBrand = $(this).val()`. Thus you will get the selected value *no matter what it is*.